# Can't assign to array I've created java

Tags: java

Im a beginner in java and im trying to use an array i've created 
but it keep not recoginze it. 
anyone know what could be the thing im missing here ?

to be more specific the command `bookArray.length` is making this error.

```
Library(int maxBookCapacity){
    Book bookArray[]= new Book[libraryMaxBookCapacity];
}

boolean inLibrary(Book book){
    for(int i=0; i<bookArray.length; i++ ){
        if (book==bookArray[i]){
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`bookArray` is a local variable and spocannot be access outside of the defining method. In fact *local* means just that: that the name `bookArray` is only available inside the constructor.

If you need it in `inLibrary` you should declare is as a field in the enclosing class:

```
public class Library {

  private final Book[] bookArray;

  public Library(int maxBookCapacity){
    bookArray = new Book[libraryMaxBookCapacity];
  }

  public boolean inLibrary(Book book){
    for(int i = 0; i < bookArray.length; i++ ){
      if (book == bookArray[i]){
        return true;
      }
    }
    return false;
  }
}
```

By the way, consider if you actually need to compare book objects with the `==` operator.

Answer (score 0):

```
// If you declare this within the constructor, it'll be a local variable and nobody can access it. 
// Having it here means that inLibrary can see it
private Book[] bookArray;

Library(int maxBookCapacity){
    // watch out here, in your code you have a different var from the parameter of the constructor
    bookArray= new Book[maxBookCapacity];
}

boolean inLibrary(Book book){
    for(int i=0; i<bookArray.length; i++ ){
        if (book==bookArray[i]){
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```